# I got an issue with Jms point to point sampler

Tags: jmeter

[image: Jms point to point sampler error]

I got:

> Response error message as javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Q.RPL

Can you please suggest solution for this issue with screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

It indicates the absence of the `Q.RPL` queue in your [JMS broker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker). Please double check whether the queue exists and its name exactly matches what you specify in your JMeter configuration.

It is also possible to [dynamically create destinations like](http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html) `dynamicQueues/Q.RPL`.

Check out [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) article for more details on load testing message queue brokers with JMeter.